# Dell Perc 5e controller. Cleared foreign configuration found on two disks. Can I still recover the old configuration?

Tags: configuration, dell-perc

Dell Perc 5e controller. 8 Disks. Two disks mistakenly removed for an operating and healthy system. Cleared foreign configuration found on (2) two disks. Can I still recover the old configuration by removing yet another disk recreating the option to recover the foreign configuration in the Open Manager?
Is the configuration found on the the controller or disks or both.